# Bootstrap tabs in modal window with Yii forms

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, tabs, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem with tabs in bootstrap modal windows with [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) framework. I already spent over a couple of hours and I'm out of ideas. I am creating media library and I want it to work like this:

1. Clicking on thumbnails image
2. Opening modal windows with tabs
3. Switching tabs show different form fields.

Unfortunately tabs don't work properly. Show bad content or don't show it at all.

[The code](http://pastebin.com/8YMsarTg).

Edit:
I use [this](http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/) plugin for multiple modal windows in foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if i should edit my post or add a new one, but i want to say that i solved this problem. The issue was that foreach loop made many id with the same names. So for example links shoud have attr href="modalcontent-1" and content tab id="modalcontent-1". It seems obvious, but somehow I missed id :)

Comment: Correct that you added the solution as an answer.